# Python get all members list from a specific role

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How to get a members list from a specific role with `!getuser` command in discord channel.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)  
async def getuser(ctx):
```

bot replys with their ID

```
 1. @user1#123
 2. @user2#123
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rewrite branch provides an attribute [`Role.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Role.members).

On the async branch, you'll have to loop through all the members of the server and check their roles.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)  
async def getuser(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name="mod")
    if role is None:
        await bot.say('There is no "mod" role on this server!')
        return
    empty = True
    for member in ctx.message.server.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await bot.say("{0.name}: {0.id}".format(member))
            empty = False
    if empty:
        await bot.say("Nobody has the role {}".format(role.mention))
```

Comment: Members of a server have a name, a discriminator, an id, and an optional server-specific nickname.  It sounds like you're looking for `"{0.name}#{0.discriminator}".format(member)`

Comment: You would remove the `role` argument, then resolve `role` in the body of the coroutine, `role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.roles, "mod")`.  You could also set `empty = True` at the beginning of the coroutine, then set it to `False` in the `if` block.  Then just check it's value after the `for` loop.

Comment: @Demotry at the top, before the loop.

Comment: `ctx.message.server.roles`.  Eventually I'll stop making that mistake...

Comment: Try with `name="mod"` instead then.

Comment: IIRC @PatrickHaugh using `str(member)` also returns the member's Discord Tag.

Comment: @Demotry I would use [`Client.get_server`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_server) over building a server object manually.

Answer (score 5):

All these solutions are too inefficient when you can just do

```
@bot.command()
async def getuser(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    await ctx.send("\n".join(str(member) for member in role.members)
```

Answer (score 2):

Patrick's answer doesn't work at all, Tristo's answer is better, but I tweaked a few things to make it work with rewrite:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def members(ctx,*args):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    role_name = (' '.join(args))
    role_id = server.roles[0]
    for role in server.roles:
        if role_name == role.name:
            role_id = role
            break
    else:
        await ctx.send("Role doesn't exist")
        return
    for member in server.members:
        if role_id in member.roles:
            await ctx.send(f"{member.display_name} - {member.id}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully a faster and more readable solution than the one before

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)  
async def getuser(ctx,*args):
  server = ctx.message.server
  role_name = (' '.join(args))
  role_id = server.roles[0]
  for role in server.roles:
    if role_name == role.name:
      role_id = role
      break
  else:
    await bot.say("Role doesn't exist")
    return    
  for member in server.members:
    if role_id in member.roles:
      await bot.say(f"{role_name} - {member.name}")
```