# Python mention random users from role

Tags: discord.py

How can I mention multiple random users from a role `member` by using a command in a discord channel.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def mention(ctx):
#   ''
await bot.say
```

Comment: Relevant: [Python get all members list from a specific role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025872/python-get-all-members-list-from-a-specific-role)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  no i don't want members list.  If i use a command `mention` it should select  a random 5 users from `member` role.

Comment: I think @PatrickHaugh pointed you at that so you could write the code to do what you want. Once you get the list you can randomly select 5 from it.

Comment: @Steve Once you have the list of members in a given role, you can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to select some number of them.

Answer (score 0):

this should work fine but it does not ping multiple members it chooses a random one from a list

````py
@client.command()
    async def mention(ctx):
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='role_name')
        members = [member for member in ctx.guild.members if role in member.roles]
        member = random.choice(members)
        await ctx.send(f'{member.mention}')```
````