# how can I display in the #channel, members with a certain role? (with discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to write a command in my (first) bot that prints in the discord channel all members
in a certain @role (in this it's called "Serf")
this is my command/function

```py
@client.command()
async def snap(ctx):
    target = discord.Role.members("Serf")
    for person in target:
        await ctx.send(person)
```

but nothing happens and I get this error in the terminal

```py
Ignoring exception in command snap:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thonkpad/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Python/thanosBot/bot.py", line 28, in snap
    target = discord.Role.members("Serf")
TypeError: 'property' object is not callable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thonkpad/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/thonkpad/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/thonkpad/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'property' object is not callable
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025872/python-get-all-members-list-from-a-specific-role)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're calling the actual discord.Role object itself and not finding the Role object of the specific role you want. You could do something like this:

```
@client.command()
async def snap(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="Serf")
    target = role.members
    for person in target:
        await ctx.send(person.name)
```

`target` will be a list of discord.Member objects