# Get all Memebers with a certain Role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been trying for quite some time to get a list of all members with a specific role,  but I fail every time.

I know that there is `role.members` but I have no idea how to use it in order to get a list of all members with a specific role.

I have looked through many questions (to get a list of members with a specific role) here on Stack Overflow, but I was not able to find a working solution

How can I get a list of all members with a specific role?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show your code and what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python get all members list from a specific role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025872/python-get-all-members-list-from-a-specific-role)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure `role` is a `discord.Role` model, [`role.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role.members) should return a `List` of `member`s. I assume you are getting an empty list, if it is then you are probably missing **Member Intents** to see the `members` of a `Role` and this is probably the reason you are only getting an empty list.

Discord.py has it is own explanation about this topic that you can read [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html).

(Also, i saw that discord.py didn't mention it but if you want to turn on all of the intents rather than specifying it, you can use [`discord.Intents.all`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.all) method to make an intent that has everything turned on in it.)