# How to the list of people that has a certain role

Tags: discord.py

I searched for it, but didn't find anything that could really help. Basically, I would like that when I run `.highrank` in a discord channel, the bots gives me a list of the people that have this role.

This is the current code I have:

```
@client.command()
        async def highrank(ctx):
            role =
           await ctx.send(role.members)
```

I do not know how to make sure that this will give me a list of the people with the high rank role in the server.

Edit: I found this, but I only get the bot name and ID when I do the command, and only if the bot has the role.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
        async def members(ctx, *args):
            server = ctx.message.guild
            role_name = (' '.join(args))
            role_id = server.roles[0]
            for role in server.roles:
                if role_name == role.name:
                    role_id = role
                    break
            else:
                await ctx.send("Role doesn't exist")
                return
            for member in server.members:
                if role_id in member.roles:
                    await ctx.send(f"{member.display_name} - {member.id}")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python get all members list from a specific role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025872/python-get-all-members-list-from-a-specific-role)

Comment: I tried this, but it only gives me a response when the bot has this role, and it only gives me the bot name and ID. This is the current script I have now. I added the new code in the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@client.command()
async def userrole(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    # this will give the length of the users in role in an embed
    members_with_role = []
    for member in role.members:
        members_with_role.append(member.name)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"**Users in {role.name}: **{len(members_with_role)}", description="\n ".join(member.mention for member in role.members)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a role by its ID:

[`ctx.guild.get_role(123456789)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Guild.get_role)

You would replace `123456789` with the role id you get by right-clicking the role (with Developer Mode enabled in Discord).

```
@client.command()
async def highrank(ctx):
    HIGHRANK_ROLE_ID = 123456789 # replace this with your role ID
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(HIGHRANK_ROLE_ID)
    await ctx.send(role.members)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`ctx.guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Guild.roles) and locate the role by name using a helper such as [`discord.utils.find`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.utils.find).

```
@client.command()
async def highrank(ctx):
    # replace the role name with your "High Rank" role's name
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.name == 'High Rank', channel.guild.roles)
    await ctx.send(role.members)
```